# How implement a select all button for an unknown number of check boxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am not sure where to begin so I do not have any code to post. I am looking to create a button that when clicked would set all the checkoxes on the page to checked or vice versa. The issue is that I do not know how many checkboxes I have and I do not assign IDs to the checkboxes since they are generated by javascript as part of result records from a search. Any ideas can I do a global all checkboxes to true or something simple like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use jquery or some other javascript library?

Comment: If the checkboxes are generated in javascript, you could just save the references to them in an array when you create them, and then act on that array.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Not necessarily. If they have been added to the DOM, you can use `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath I wasn't saying you couldn't.  I was proposing an alternative - if your javascript is creating the checkboxes, your javascript *can* (not must, just can) just as easily track the checkboxes, without having to do a full search of the DOM.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Sorry for misinterpreting. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard JavaScript:

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    nodeList[i].checked = true;
}
```

With jQuery:

```
jQuery("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the magic `document.querySelectorAll()` function to accomplish this in Vanilla JS

http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/vcWrw/

Answer (score 1):

If you used jquery for e.g., you could use any of the [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to select the checkboxes and then apply a manipulation, such as setting their value.

```
$( "[type=checkbox]" ).prop("checked", false)
```